# Need help understanding preprocessor message macros in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I haven't had a need to use preprocessor macros much before, and came across this bit of code on the web:

```
#ifndef LITE_VERSION 
    #ifndef FULL_VERSION
        #error
    #endif 
#endif
```

The goal of this is to warn if either LITE or FULL is not declared.  I've dropped this in my Prefix.pch file and I receive a warning with the #error statement.

I tried changing the error to:

```
#pragma message("some text")
```

And while this will compile, no text is displayed (that I can see).

I've not declared the LITE or FULL yet, so I'm wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: Whats your problem exactly? You do or do not want to see the #error message when LITE_VERSION/FULL_VERSION are not defined? If you dont then you should just take out the whole macro. If your using the latest version of XCode your pragma should be causing a warning to show up in your debug console.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted the warning when I build, not the error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be:

```
#pragma message "some text"
```

Or you could use this if you prefer:

```
#pragma message ("some text")
```

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Typically I use a slightly different approach:

```
#if defined(LITE_VERSION)
   ...
#elseif defined(FULL_VERSION)
   ...
#else
#error "Must define LITE_VERSION or FULL_VERSION"
#end
```

Comment: Oh wait, I feel silly.  I thought this would simply place a warning message on the console and it's actually producing the error preventing the build.  =)

Comment: Strangely, though, #pragma message "some text" doesn't show anything on the console...

Comment: Did you view the entire build output? I would expect it to be in there. Note that in my above example, I use #error on purpose to break the build. Otherwise, you blithely run along, not digging through every line of build output. Same reason I believe in -Werror. Making the build stop is how you get a developer's attention.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the error as you had it before. Just add a message and build

```
#ifndef LITE_VERSION
    #ifndef FULL_VERSION
        #error "Neither Lite or Full version has been defined"
    #endif
#endif
```